# Vole Wizard Hovels

Tags: word, english, word-property

The following <del>nine</del> ten words (thank you Bass) are the only words in the entire English language* that have a certain extraordinary property:

- bevy
- by
- girt
- grit
- hovels
- lo
- vole
- wizard
- wold
- > trig

What is that property?

* that I was able to find, based on a search of a 100,000-word English dictionary. (excluding names and abbreviations)

Comment: Great question!

Comment: By symmetry, shouldn't [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trig) count too?

Comment: Did you search the dictionary _by hand_??!!??

Comment: @Brandon_J - I used my hands to type in the code of the Perl script that did the searching. Does that count as searching by hand? :)

Comment: @Bass - That showed up in my list, but I originally discarded it as an abbreviation, and therefore not a proper word. But now that you point it out, I think I was wrong to leave it out. It's not really an abbreviation, it's just informal shorthand.

Comment: An American President and a French novelist also have this property.

Comment: @Quuxplusone - Indeed they do, but I did not include proper names in my search because it seemed too much like cheating. There are endless different names out there, and people invent new names all the time. (I could name my cat "Vaucbshyxfze", and then legitimately claim the name exists.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the property is

> that applying the Atbash cipher (replacing each letter with its alphabetic inverse - $A \leftrightarrow Z, B \leftrightarrow Y$, etc.) yields the same result as reversing the word.

In other words,

> the first and last, second and second-to-last, etc. letters in each word are alphabetic inverses: B and Y, E and V, I and R, L and O, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> The First letter is as far away from the beginning of the alphabet as the last letter is to the end.

Comment: The words `wood`, `birthday`, and `goat` satisfy the rule you have specified, but are **not** on plasticinsect's list.

Comment: ah I see, the real answer was that the rule applied to the letters inside the word not just the ends.